# Disk encryption: advantages and drawbacks of hardware disk encription vs dm-crypt

Tags: linux, ssd, encryption, aes, fde

I'm going to reinstall my system (Ubuntu) on a Samsung 840 pro SSD. This disk can do AES hardware encryption.
I wonder what would be the drawbacks and/or advantages of taking this approach versus using LVM full disk encryption from these perspectives:

- security: are these methods equivalent in term of security?
- convenience: I'd like to avoid typing too many passwords.
- recovery/compatibility: what if I have to take the disk and mount it in another computer to recover my data ?

Comment: An added comment regarding security: using built-in AES also requires you trust your hardware manufacturer... (well, simply using their disk probably implies you have to trust them)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- **security:** The drive offers AES. dm-crypt offers your own choice, if you're not satisfied with AES. Both can be erased very quickly by erasing the key.
- **convenience:** both methods will prompt for a password once, at startup; although you *could* store the LUKS keyfile on an external device, e.g. a USB memory stick

  - with dm-crypt, you have the flexibility to only encrypt parts of your system, e.g. only the /home directory (when put on a separate partition)
- **recovery:** if you forget the drive password, you're *busted*. For LUKS, you *could* (depending on the level paranoia you want to accept) have multiple copies of your key. Printed on a sheet of paper, if you want to. Or hidden inside a book. Or ...

  - Both are not dependent on the surrounding hardware, so your disk can be recovered even if the original laptop/PC dies.
- **performance:** the device built-in encryption should be mostly transparent, so I assume almost no overhead. With dm-crypt, your CPU does the en-/decryption.

  - Also: *In linux 3.1 and up, support for dm-crypt TRIM pass-through can be toggled upon device creation or mount with dmsetup.* So you need to take some steps, but TRIM is supported.

To summarize: the built-in encryption is the fast (runtime and setup) and convenient option with no frills. dm-crypt/LuKS offer many more options and features, but is more time-consuming to set up and reduces performance somewhat.

Comment: Regarding recovery, notice that built-in AES is dependant on the way the BIOS passes the password to the disk. For example, see http://monitor.espec.ws/files/lewnovo_password_399.pdf

Answer (score 3):

Use the built-in AES.
Why?

- It's powerful enough.
- It supports TRIM and it's supported by the manufacturer.
- You don't have to use a strong password as your Linux login pass.
- As far as I know, [you can use it in an other system](http://dfarq.homeip.net/2011/04/intels-and-sandforces-aes-128-encryption-is-useful-but-not-for-what-you-think/).

Answer (score 0):

built in:
+ much faster
+ easier to set up
- you have no idea about the implementation, might be superb, might be crap

dm-crypt:
+ slower
- you can check the implementation yourself (theoretically anyway)

recovery - with dm crypt what ypu said works, with the build in it's unknown, theoretically if the bios passes the ata password unchanged it should work fine, otherwise...

Comment: Regarding recovery, I've found that my Bios does not leave ata password unchanged (Lenovo Thinkpad bios). Seems to be working like this http://monitor.espec.ws/files/lewnovo_password_399.pdf but as hdparm --security-set-pass cannot cope with binary password, I couldn't test...